# Converting string to data masking with dyplr inside function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function which restructures some data. I got this function to work and it looked somehthing like this:

```
function_1 <- function(df, group, focal, reference){
  if (reference == "rest"){
    df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate({{group}} := recode({{group}}, {{focal}} := {{focal}}, .default = "rest"))
    df <- df %>% dplyr::select(ac_id, question_id, question_result_score, {{group}})
    df <- df[!(duplicated(dplyr::select(df, ac_id, question_id))), ]
    df <- df %>% dplyr::arrange(ac_id)
  }
  else{
    df <- dplyr::filter(df, {{group}} == {{focal}} | {{group}} == {{reference}})
    df <- df %>% dplyr::select(ac_id, question_id, question_result_score, {{group}})
    df <- df[!(duplicated(dplyr::select(df, ac_id, question_id))), ]
    df <- df %>% dplyr::arrange(ac_id)
  }
  return(df)
}
# and I run the following command:
function_1(mydata, gender, "male", "rest")
```

This works exactly as I want it to. Now this needs to go inside another function (let's call this `function_2`), where I loop over different demographic characteristics (age, gender, english-native, etc.) and demographic indicators (e.g. "male" (from gender), "female" (from gender), etc.).

Inside `function_2` we loop over the output of another function, which returns a dataframe with the following structure:

| group | focal | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gender | female | male |
| gender | female | rest |
| gender | male | rest |
| english | native | non-native |
| ... | ... | ... |

The problem when looping over this output is (I THINK) that the input of `function_1` becomes:

```
function_1(mydata, "gender", "female", "male")
#instead of 
function_1(mydata, gender, "female", "male")
```

So without the quotation marks. Does anybody know a way how to fix `function_1` such that it works with input as shown above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any other information let me know!

KR

P.S.
Maybe the following helps. To generate the table as shown above, we use a function which I stored in a variable called `viable_cat` and this output has the following properties:

````
typeof(viable_cat)
[1] "character"
> class(viable_cat)
[1] "matrix" "array" ```
````

Comment: Hard to guess what the exact problem is. Looks like `deparse(substitute(value))` would solve your problem. Can you provide some sample data using `dput`?

Comment: The exact problem lies in the fact that in 

`df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate({{group}} := recode({{group}}, {{focal}} := {{focal}}, .default = "rest"))` the {{group}} doesn't work anymore when a string is passed instead of a data masking I think. Will check out dput and see if I can provide some data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `!!sym(.)` for turning strings into variable names. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
in_var = "mpg"
out_var = "mpg2"

new = mtcars %>%
  mutate(!!sym(out_var) := 2 * !!sym(in_var))
```

You can pass strings between multiple functions with ease.

I know this technique is not recommended by [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). It is an older approach for programming with dplyr. I find it more applicable to my use cases than some of the options currently recommended.